# How to get values of dictionary in array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, ios8

I have dictionary like this

```
var dict : [String : Array<String>] = ["Fruits" : ["Mango", "Apple", "Banana"],"Flowers" : ["Rose", "Lotus","Jasmine"],"Vegetables" : ["Tomato", "Potato","Chilli"]]
```

I want to get values in array for each key How to get it in swift?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

EDIT:
Try Something like this,

```
var dict : [String : Array<String>] = [
                                        "Fruits" : ["Mango", "Apple", "Banana"],
                                        "Flowers" : ["Rose", "Lotus","Jasmine"],
                                        "Vegetables" : ["Tomato", "Potato","Chilli"]
                                      ]


var myArray : Array<String> = []
// You can access the dictionary(dict) by the keys(Flowers, Flowers, Vegetables)
// Here I'm appending the array(myArray), by the accessed values.
myArray += dict["Fruits"]!
myArray += dict["Vegetables"]!

print("myArray \(myArray)")
```

**Above is how to get values of dictionay in swift, 
If you want to get contatenated array of all the values of 
dictionary(*only values),
Try something like below.**

```
print("values array : \(dict.map{$0.value}.flatMap{$0})")
```

> values array : ["Rose", "Lotus", "Jasmine", "Tomato", "Potato",
>   "Chilli", "Mango", "Apple", "Banana"]

Answer (score 21):

2½ years and no-one mentioned `map`?

ok, set aside that `Dictionary` has a [property `values`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894304-values)(as [ameenihad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45949794/106435) shows) which will do what you asking for, you could do:

```
let values = dict.map { $0.value }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var a:Array = dict["Fruits"]! ;

println(a[0])//mango

println(a[1])//apple
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
for (key, value) in dict {
    println("key=\(key), value=\(value)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to get values as like following code

```
let fruits = dict["Fruits"]
let flowers = dict["Flowers"]
let vegetables = dict["Vegetables"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for val in dict.values {
    print("Value -> \(val)")
}
```